# Find the final velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

[image]

I am unable to find the expression for initial energy so that "conservation of energy would help".

Another way can be finding the linear impulse. But how would that work out?

Only if $∮E.dl = -dΦ/dt$ helps out, but I need a suitable loop for it.

Comment: Hi ! I found your problem rather hard. It took me some time to figure out the solution. What kind of studies are you presently following ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Along that face in the z-x plane, integral gives, 2E(a+h)=ah(B/dt) => 2Ea =ah(B/dt) => E(dt)=B×h/2.       => F(dt)=qE(dt)   =>   F(dt) = 2σab(Bh/2)=mv

Comment: For direction, net force due to induced electric field will cancer out in z-direction(by symmetry) and the only remaining effective components will be along +x-axis

Comment: Hmmmm... Where does the $ab$ come from into your final formula ? Also your notation is incorrect, if you use differentials E(dt) instead of derivatives ("dt" at denominator of right-hand-side) then the  right-hand-side should also be a differential in terms of dB, not B. Except for that, your are right. Just simplify by 2 !

Comment: Also, if you are happy, please click on the "check" signe next to my answer so I get my 15 points of reputation. You also will get reputations points for doing that, but only 2. That would still triple your own present reputation !!!

Comment: About my previous post: once you have both sides as differentials, **then** you can integrate both differentials from initial time to final time. But multiplying by $dt$ is meaningless in the right-hand-side is a quantity rather than the differential of a quantity. In fact, use derivatives rather than differentials (I mean, just leave $dt$ at the denominator) if you are not familiar with the use of differentials. It is the same thing, really, but you got mixed up.

Comment: @Alfred B/dt implies rapid change in magnetic field since it was switched off to instananeously. Also integral(F(dt))=m.∆v would be impulse-momentum theorem.

Comment: For ab, q=σ(ab) as per the charge density given in original question. Sorry for rough reply, yet it has nothing to do with differentials. Yet I suppose replacing dt with 't' would be better as per your reply.

Comment: Ah, I had missed that it was a charge density. Indeed $\sigma$ is typical for charge density, not charge... RE :$t$ rather than $dt$ NOOOOOO ! You have no indication on the precise time dependance of B(t). The ONLY  thing you know is that you start from $B=B_0$ and end at $B=0$. So you integrate both sides of $$d(mv)/dt=F(t)=abh\sigma \ dB/dt$$ and you dont care how $dB/dt$ behaves since you care only on the boundary values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "homework and exercise" I am not supposed to solve the problem for you but just give you a hint.

The only loops that make sense here are those around rectangles of length $a$ and height $h$, all along the side of length $b$. There is a magnetic flux in each of these loops. In fact rather than loops, you have to think of the situation as a sheet folded over itself, with a magnetic flux going through it, and charges on top and on bottom, but an isolating sheet, so the charges cannot cross from top to bottom.

Your idea of using $$∮E.dl = -dΦ/dt$$ is the good one.

Just remember that $h$ is **negligible** compared to $a$ and $b$. This is **very important**

I hope that helps !